# How to move terminal cursor with ASCII code?

Tags: c, bash, terminal, ncurses

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("asd");
    char code[4] = { 0x08 ,  0x1b , 0x5b ,0x4b } ; 
    int i = 0 ; 
    while ( i  < 4  )
    {   
        putc(code[i], stdout);
        i++;
    }   
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

output:

[root@localhost ~]# ./a.out

as

[root@localhost ~]#

It seems that code "0x08" move terminal cursor left to  letter "d" position  ,and "0x1b , 0x5b ,0x4b"  clear up letter "d" .
I want to know the meaning of some codes like { 0x08 ,  0x1b , 0x5b ,0x4b } . Is there  relevant information  available ?

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to refer to ASCII codes. http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Thanks for replying . I use putc( 0x4b , stdout) . It will print character 'K' to terminal . But it will not print K while I putc " 0x08 , 0x1b , 0x5b ,0x4b " one by one . So i guess that codes " 0x08 , 0x1b , 0x5b ,0x4b " control terminal appearance like a command .

Comment: @rcs: ASCII doesn't specify terminal codes. [konsolebox's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24629164/827263) points to a Wikipedia article about so-called ANSI escape codes (which are really defined by ISO/IEC 6429 / ECMA-48).

Answer (score 7):

See [ANSI escape code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

One simple way you can do it is

```
printf("\e[10C%s\n", "XYZ");
```

It would move cursor 10 columns to the right and print XYZ:

```
          XYZ
```

Comment: ;\e' for escape is non-standard; gcc supports it, but other compilers might not. Use '\x1b' instead if you want more portable code.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks. Never knew that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the \x1b escape can also be written as \033

Answer (score 0):

another example to support my guess :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("asd");
    char code[8] = { 0x08 ,  0x1b , 0x5b ,0x4b , 0x08 ,  0x1b , 0x5b ,0x4b } ; 
    int i = 0 ; 
    while ( i  < 8  )
    {   
        putc(code[i], stdout);
        i++;
    }   

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

output:

[root@localhost ~]# ./a.out

a

[root@localhost ~]#